# Looking for ENCRYPTION options for UIImage using Swift 3

Tags: encryption

This may be a broad question but I am exploring encryption for an app I am developing.  In particular I am seeking advice for which I would like to encrypt images stored on the google.firebase database.  Please help!

I am currently using swift 3 and Xcode 8 and building iOS apps.

Thank-you!